# a set A not open or closed not is homeomorphic to $X/A-[A]$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

the problem says:

Find an example showing that if $A ⊂ X$ is not open or closed, then $X −A$ need not be homeomorphic $X/A−[A]$.

I have dealt with the Sorgenfrey line (which has the lower boundary topology) or in the real ones but I did not get to much.

Comment: Try $X = \Bbb{R}$ and $A = \Bbb{Q}$.